# How can I reset my user account password on OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, authentication

My MacBook keeps saying that my password is wrong. I haven't changed it in a year. I have tried to reboot it, but I have no idea how to do it. I have my laptop in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plausible way of resetting the password of your login on your OS X is to:

1. Go to Single-user mode (<kbd>CMD</kbd>  + <kbd>S</kbd> on boot)
2. Type: `/sbin/mount -uw /` and press Enter
3. Type `rm /var/db/.applesetupdone` and press Enter
4. Type `reboot` and press Enter.

On boot, you will be prompted to setup like if your mac was new. Don't panic, as your data is not lost (I would backup just in case though). Skip all unnecessary options, and later you will be prompted to create a new admin account.

Once your setup finishes, from the new account, go to **System Preferences** > **Users and Groups**, click on your previous username and click **Reset Password**. Now type in the new password and login as your old account.

Comment: This did not work all it did was reboot my computer back to the password screen

Comment: If CMD+S did not work, it might be because of FileVault. You can disable it from Recovery. Also, try doing step 2 and 3 in the Recovery command line since it is a root command line just like single-user mode

Comment: It worked it was just me being dumb, when I got into my settings to change my password, I kept trying to remember my password to change it but didn't realise I had to leave the old password box blank  Thank you for your help

Comment: @Taychowder Im happy that it worked :) You can now tick my answer to mark question as solved